# How to convert french date to english date?

Tags: jsp

My english and french date format is dd-MMM-yyyy. I am working for an application where two locales are used English and french.
When English locale is selected everything is working fine but when french locale is selected then it cannot convert french date to english date. How can i convert french date to English date in jsp page?

Comment: Show us some code. A date is a date. It can be represented as a String, and that depends on the locale, but a date is not linked to any locale.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getInstance();
df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT,
             DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.FRENCH);
```

and for more detail see this

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateFormat.html